# How to generate HL7 message?

Tags: python, odoo, hl7, hl7-v3

I want to send the data of patient to the dcm4chee using the python code, Currently I am able to send the data to the modality worklist using the "MLLPClient" but I have HL7 message which is generated by the openMRS, can any one help to know that how can I generate custom HL7 message using the patient data in python (odoo).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38567996/how-to-get-multiple-obr-segment-from-hl7-message         ** Solution**

Comment: https://msarfati.wordpress.com/2015/06/22/python-hl7-v2-x-and-hl7apy-hl7-construction-with-ormo01-and-orur01-part-2/  Help to generate HL7 using hl7apy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the blog which helps me to create HL7 message.

https://msarfati.wordpress.com/2015/06/22/python-hl7-v2-x-and-hl7apy-hl7-construction-with-ormo01-and-orur01-part-2/

In this blog the given code for OBR segment,
You need to do: OrderDetailGroup before adding and populating the OBR segment.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Hapi could help you: http://hl7api.sourceforge.net/hapi-testpanel/install.html . It generates HL7 messages and I guess it could build hL7 messages with your own data.

Good luck!

Comment: Is there any python library ??

Comment: I tried HL7apy but when I try to add segment OBR is not working, Here the code is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38567996/how-to-get-multiple-obr-segment-from-hl7-message

Comment: do you guys know the syntax of adding multiple OBX to the same patient? i couldn't find online..