# How to ADD OBR to the HL7 message?

Tags: python, hl7, hl7-v2, hl7-v3

I am trying to generate the HL7 message using the Python library hl7apy, but when HL7 message is generate it does not gives the OBR segment in the output, please try to solve this query.

The code is

```
from hl7apy import core
hl7 = core.Message("ORM_O01")
hl7.msh.msh_3 = "SendingApp"
hl7.msh.msh_4 = "SendingFac"
hl7.msh.msh_5 = "ReceivingApp"
hl7.msh.msh_6 = "ReceivingFac"
hl7.msh.msh_9 = "ORM^O01^ORM_O01"
hl7.msh.msh_10 = "168715"
hl7.msh.msh_11 = "P"

# PID
hl7.add_group("ORM_O01_PATIENT")
hl7.ORM_O01_PATIENT.pid.pid_2 = "1"
hl7.ORM_O01_PATIENT.pid.pid_3 = "A-10001"
hl7.ORM_O01_PATIENT.pid.pid_5 = "B-10001"
hl7.ORM_O01_PATIENT.pid.pid_6 = "DOE^JOHN"

# ORC
hl7.ORM_O01_ORDER.orc.orc_1 = "1"
hl7.ORM_O01_ORDER.ORC.orc_10 = "20150414120000"

# OBR
# We must explicitly add the OBR segment, then populate fields
hl7.ORM_O01_ORDER.ORM_O01_ORDER_DETAIL.ORM_O01_OBSERVATION.ORM_O01_ORDER_CHOICE.add_segment("OBR")
hl7.ORM_O01_ORDER.ORM_O01_ORDER_DETAIL.ORM_O01_OBSERVATION.ORM_O01_ORDER_CHOICE.OBR.obr_2 = "1"
hl7.ORM_O01_ORDER.ORM_O01_ORDER_DETAIL.ORM_O01_OBSERVATION.ORM_O01_ORDER_CHOICE.OBR.obr_3 = "2"
hl7.ORM_O01_ORDER.ORM_O01_ORDER_DETAIL.ORM_O01_OBSERVATION.ORM_O01_ORDER_CHOICE.OBR.obr_4 = "1100"

assert hl7.validate() is True

print "\n Validate HL7 Message: ", hl7.validate()

print "\n\n HL7 Message : \n\n", hl7.value
print "\n\n"
# Returns True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a OrderDetailGroup before adding and populating the OBR segment.